# Carbon dioxide concentration in alkaline media

Tags: bacteriology, organic-chemistry, ph, growth-media

I am running a batch experiment using penicillin bottles where I have bacteria growing for 21 days in a highly alkaline media (pH 10). I am measuring the CO2 and O2 content in the headspace over time, but I am specially interested in the CO2 production. Usually I can simply use the CO2 content measured with a gas-chromatographer (GC) but because of the pH of my media, the CO2 will be dissolved into my media. This I have seen in the sharp drop of pH over time as well.

I want then, to calculate the amount of CO2 that has dissolved into my media. I know I require Dalton's Law of partial pressures and Henry's constant/Law. The thing is that, I am a bit confused because as I measured the pressure inside my closed bottles, the pressure in these bottles became negative. So my calculations are returning a negative value for my concentration of gas in the solution. Furthermore, I do not know if the formulas I used (Dalton  and Henry), take into consideration the pH of my aqueous media.

Comment: What salts are present in you media? Something like calcium will precipitate with carbon dioxide and removed from your system.

Comment: It's just a TSB media adjusted with CAPS buffer. No precipitation was observed.